# FreeTDS strange date time format

Tags: php, freetds

After moving application to new server with updated software (moved from php 5.2.17 -> 5.3.15, FreeTDS  0.64 -> 0.82)

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

and any other datetime  function / column produces something similar to:

```
2012-06-219 51:527:
// proper time: 2012-08-06 09:33:02
```

I know I can use `convert` in select, but there are many stored procedures in DB that I can not change.

I tried to change `/etc/locales.conf` and setting `date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, and using `ini_set('mssql.datetimeconvert',1);` but freetds seems to ignore it and returns `Aug 06 2012 09:33AM`

Is there a way to retrieve datetime columns in standard format, without modifying every query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue in a kind of brute force way - changed `date format` in all locales in `/etc/locales.conf`, I don't know which one worked, but I'm pretty sure that none of them was used as system locale.

Anyway, using `datetimeconvert` is not advised, and turned off in some db abstract layer libraries (adodb in this case) so I'm still interested if there is any way to make it display proper date time

Comment: can you share (without anys ensitive info) you locales.conf please? Also.. do I have to restart apache after changing the settings?

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have access to this project. I'm pretty sure that you need restart Apache (if it runs php as module) or PHP-FPM if it runs as FastcGI pass-through configuration.